# Difference between VMWare Bridged network and Docker ipvlan/macvlan?

Tags: docker, linux-networking, virtualbox, bridge, virtual-network

In Virtual Networking, I have seen two techniques to connect the guest machine with the Host machines **network**.

**In VMWare/VirtualBox** - Bridged Networking is used to connect the guest machine with the host machines **network**.
Ex - if the host is on `172.16.0.1/12 subnet` with IP `172.16.0.2` as host IP,
then using Bridge networking any guest running on the above host can be connected to the host network i.e  `172.16.0.1/12 subnet` and the guest will receive an IP on this subnet say 172.16.0.6 (just picked a random valid IP in this subnet).

**In Docker**, the same is achieved using IPVLAN or MACVLAN.
Ex: - if host is on `172.16.0.1/12 subnet` with IP `172.16.0.2` as host IP,
then using MACVLAN or IPVLAN  any container running on this host can be connected to host network i.e  `172.16.0.1/12 subnet` and the container will receive an IP on this subnet say 172.16.0.6 (again, just picked a random valid IP in this subnet).

Though the end result is same, the techniques used seem to be different. Am I right?
So just exploring to understand the difference between these two approches and how bridging differs from IPVLAN/MACVLAN?

Comment: some doc would help: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking/ , https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ipvlan.txt